# Deleting Entity with Foreign Key Relationship Without Deleting Reference Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, reference, foreign-keys

My problem is with the generic "Delete" in the BidController I am getting the typical Error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "fkw_....". The conflict occurred in database table ..., column ....
>   The statement has been terminated.

Thank you so much for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I am able to set the GUID to null, so I am posting a simple answer.

In my BidController I have updated my code:

```
        item = null;
```

This removes the reference to the bid and so the bids are free to be removed!

Answer (score 1):

Try making the relationship as OPTIONAL. This way your items can have null Foreign Keys.

If you are using database first approach:

```
CREATE TABLE Item(
    ItemId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ActiveBidId INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Bid(BidId)
    // ...
  );
```

If you already created the table, then you can alter your table as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE Item 
DROP CONSTRAINT FK_ActiveBidConstraint -- The name of your  constraint
GO

ALTER TABLE Item
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ActiveBidConstraint FOREIGN KEY (ActiveBidId) -- The name of your  constraint
    REFERENCES Bid(BidId);
```

Comment: How do I mark the relationship as optional in my code? and the foreign key is null initially as the items do not have any bids on them (it shows up in the db column as null)

Comment: Can you please provide us with your models' code? Then I will tell you how to do it.

Comment: I see you have a one-to-one relationship between Item and Bid. Did you created a middle table or just created a FK column on each table?

Comment: Thank you for your help Luis, I was somehow able to simply set my GUID to null.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the ActiveBidId with a null  value and then delete the bids.That way you break the link between the Item and Bid and than you can remove the Data from Bids.

Comment: Thank you, I swear I tried to set it to null already but it gave me an error. Code given below!